# Enable targeted notification of stabilized rust compiler features in codebase

Tags: rust

There are certain parts of my code that would benefit from Rust compiler features that have yet to be stabilized.

And so, in those places, I have written less-than-ideal code so that it compiles with the stable version of rustc with a `// todo:` comment to reminde me that once the specific feature is stabilized, I should go ahead and clean up that code.

As my code grows, that's easy to get lost.  So I'm wondering if there is a mechanism for rustc to remind me when a desired feature has stabilized.  For example, I'd like to write something like

```rust
// Notify when #![feature(specialization)] is stabilizes
```

in my code, so that when I upgrade rustc, and that feature has stabilized, it emits a message on next compilation that says something like

```
model/mod.rs:71:13: feature 'specialization' is now available and can be used.
```

Is there a solution something to this effect?

Comment: you could write a cicd pipeline that runs with the latest compiler

Answer (score 3):

This feature doesn't exist. I can think of two things that can get you close.

First, you can make a separate project or a plain .rs file with all your unstable features, and then when you want to check if something has been stabilized, compile it with the nightly compiler. For example, here's a feature that is already stable:

```rust
#![feature(min_const_generics)]
```

Which produces the following warning:

```rust
warning: the feature `min_const_generics` has been stable since 1.51.0 and no longer requires an attribute to enable
 --> src\lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | #![feature(min_const_generics)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(stable_features)]` on by default
```

This method is good because with one file, you can tell no action is needed if everything compiles without warnings. However, this warning will start appearing a few months before the feature is actually released in the stable channel.

Another thing you can do is make a file for each feature you want, and put some code using that feature inside it. Then, when it successfully compiles, you know the feature is stable.

```rust
pub trait A {
    fn f();
}

impl<T> A for T {
    default fn f() {}
}
```

```rust
error[E0658]: specialization is unstable
 --> src\lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     default fn f() {}
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #31844 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844> for more information

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
```

This would require a separate file for each feature, and won't be guaranteed to have graceful errors if the feature changes shape before stabilization, but will have the correct timing if it does work. It also has the slight advantage of working when the feature you wanted has been split into multiple features. For example, this one should work when `min_specialization` is stabilized, if that happens before `specialization`.

Another thing you can do is subscribe to [the tracking issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the posted answer, another option is to gate the features and any modules utilizing them behind their own feature, then `cargo build` with that feature enabled to probe the status of stabilized features.

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[features]
    report-stabilized = []
```

main.rs or lib.rs:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(feature = "report-stabilized", feature(min_const_generics))]
#[cfg(feature = "report-stabilized")]
mod stabilization {
    pub trait A {
        fn f();
    }

    impl<T> A for T {
        default fn f() {}
    }
}
```

```bash
$ cargo build
[ all ok ]

$ cargo build --features report-stabilized
error[E0658]: specialization is unstable
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         default fn f() {}
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #31844 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(specialization)]` to the crate attributes to enable

warning: the feature `min_const_generics` has been stable since 1.51.0 and no longer requires an attribute to enable
 --> src/main.rs:1:52
  |
1 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "report-stabilized", feature(min_const_generics))]
  |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(stable_features)]` on by default

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
```